# LaunchDaemon for pf won't load at startup

Tags: macos, launchd, firewall

I have a plist in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` that should run as root on startup.

When I run `sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist`, it works. However on reboot it does not work.

Interestingly, after reboot, when I run that command it says `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist: service already loaded` but it is not functioning. However, if I unload and load it works normally.

Nothing appears in my error reporting `/tmp/pfctl.err`.

My plist is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.apple.pfctl</string>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>pfctl</string>
                <string>-e</string>
                <string>-f</string>
                <string>/etc/pf.conf</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
<key>StandardErrorPath</key>
<string>/tmp/pfctl.err</string>
<key>StandardOutPath</key>
<string>/tmp/pfctl.out</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Can you post the boot messages specific to `pfctl` by issuing the command `dmesg | grep -i pfctl`  We need to see what errors are being generated, if any.

Comment: Try changing `<string>pfctl</string>` to `<string>/sbin/pfctl</string>` or add `<key>Program</key>` and `<string>/sbin/pfctl</string>` before `ProgramArguements`.

Comment: for the record `dmesg | grep -i pfctl` didn't show any output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there is a default plist for pfctl at `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist`. They were conflict.

In that plist I set `<key>Disabled</key>` to `<true/>`, and everything works as expected.